# How to inject configuration once in the Specflow?

Tags: c#, specflow

I build and register configuration with my custom values:

```
 IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .Build();
 container.RegisterInstanceAs<IConfiguration>(configuration);
```

this is done inside method with `[BeforeScenario(Order = 1)]` annotation, I'd like to do it in method annotated by `[BeforeTestRun]` tag, but this one needs to be static. This means that I can't inject `BoDi` DI container into this method.

Thus how to load the configuration only once per test run and make it avaialble everywhere by DI container?

Comment: What's wrong with loading it once for each scenario?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Not much, but I view it as overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registering the configuration once per scenario is how SpecFlow is meant to work so tests are thread safe and can be run in parallel. That being said, reading a config file should be pretty safe, even in a multi-threaded environment. You can initialize the config once using a static field, and then register the same instance before each scenario:

```
private static IConfiguration config;

[BeforeScenario]
public void CreateConfig()
{
    if (config == null)
    {
        config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
    }

     container.RegisterInstanceAs<IConfiguration>(config);
}
```

Comment: The difference is the config is only initialized once in my answer, but registered each scenario. It appears you are initializing it each scenario. You can't do what you want to do, but using a static field allows you to initialize it once.

Comment: SpecFlow provides a number of [hooks](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks) out of the box.  You probably want to do this in BeforeTestRun to avoid the static variable.

Comment: @Fran: Are you able to access the IObjectContainer in a BeforeTestRun hook?

Comment: What is container. and where is it defined? This is not clear